# Appending elements with similar index in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to append elements of `A (shape=(1,10,2))` with the same `j` to create a new array `A1`. For example, `[1,3]` and `[2,3]` should be appended into one element because of same `j` (=3) and different `i` (=1 and =2 respectively). The desired output is attached.

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[
        [0, 1],
        [0, 2],
        [1, 3],
        [2, 3],
        [2, 4],
        [3, 5],
        [3, 6],
        [4, 6],
        [5, 7],
        [6, 7]]])
```

The desired output is

```
A1=array([[
        [0, 1],
        [0, 2],
        [[1, 3],[2, 3]],
        [2, 4],
        [3, 5],
        [[3, 6],[4, 6]],
        [[5, 7],[6, 7]]]])
A1.shape=(1,7,2)
```

Comment: I don't think this makes sense. Some of your elements are integers, others are lists. All elements in a numpy array have to be the same datatype.

Comment: You can do this with lists, but not with numpy arrays.  `A1[0][1]` is a list of 2 numbers.  `A1[0][2]` is a list of two lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it using the following steps. The only problem is that you can't have the final result as an array because of varying sizes. If you convert the result to a numpy array it becomes an array of lists of shape (7,).

You can however still iterate through it with for loops if it's not a huge list.

If you are using it in neural networks, you might want to consider converting to a [ragged tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/ragged/constant)

Get the list of second numbers

```
second_numbers = A[:,:,1].reshape(-1)
```

Get unique values from that list

```
uniq = set(second_numbers)
```

Create new list based on those unique values

```
new_list = []
for i in uniq:
  new_list.append((A[:, second_numbers == i, :].reshape(-1,2)).tolist())
```

Full code with result:

```
second_numbers = A[:,:,1].reshape(-1)
uniq = set(second_numbers)
new_list = []
for i in uniq:
  new_list.append((A[:, second_numbers == i, :].reshape(-1,2)).tolist())

new_list
>>> [[[0, 1]],
 [[0, 2]],
 [[1, 3], [2, 3]],
 [[2, 4]],
 [[3, 5]],
 [[3, 6], [4, 6]],
 [[5, 7], [6, 7]]]
```